# Are there any sites dedicated to developing expansions for the GPIO port?

Tags: gpio, hardware, software-development

I am surprised on how there seems nothing developed for the input/output pin on the Raspberry Pi. So the question is, are there any sites (websites) that host projects of shields or similar for the input/output pins of the Raspberry Pi? I am thinking of a website like lumberjocks for woodworking but for the Raspberry Pi!

Thanks for viewing and any help on this matter.

Comment: There is a relatively large number of add-ons for the Pi that use or expand the GPIO capabilities and related connections on the 26-way header pins. It is also remarkably easy to connect discrete devices such as (for example) a DS18B20 temperature sensor and collect data over the "1-Wire" bus using a shell script or program in various languages. You might enjoy the [MagPi](http://www.themagpi.com/)

Comment: Googling "Raspberry Pi HAT" will also give some results. Sadly those efforts are indeed disorganized , and the HAT specification in itself is a bit inflexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google of Raspberry Pi Expansion Boards returns huge list of add-ons, including 
[RPi Expansion Boards](http://elinux.org/RPi_Expansion_Boards) and [Raspberry Pi Forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewforum.php?f=16)

Have fun!

Comment: not exactly what i was talking about. found nothing but businesses selling expansion boards. which is really great because i couldnt find even that, now that i know you can make expansion boards for Raspberry Pi, this is going to be fun. i was more into looking for normal people making the boards and posting what they made and how it works and maybe how to build it. in other words "custom build" or "home built".

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry to disappoint you, but RasPi is more like a computer running Linux with GUI and the whole nine yards, than some kind of microchip intended for being accessed with an iron and/or the breadboard. Sure, there are GPIO pins, but so are "IO pins" in my desktop inside the PCI connector.

If you're looking for a cheap linux playground, where you may interface standard USB/HDMI/video/audio devices to a palm-sized computer, you are on the right tracks with RasPi. But if you're looking for something more hardware-related, probably you'd be better off with Arduino or BeagleBoard or hundreds of other microcontroller-based designs.